# Difference between round() and float() in Python

Tags: python, rounding

Could someone explain me what's the difference between **round()** and **float()** in Python, please?

### For example

```
x = 9.09128239
x = float("{0:.2f}".format(x))

y = 9.09128239
y = round(y, 2)
```

As I see, both functions from the code above do the same job. However, **round()** seems more compact and appealing to me.

I'd like to know if there is something else behind these functions and if I should consider something in particular when choosing which one to use.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you missed the documentation of [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) and [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)?

Comment: `float` works on `digit` and `string` as well while 'round' works on `digits` only.for more see documentation as also suggested by @Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the float function that is doing the rounding here.

As a general term, float and round do very different things. [Float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) takes a valid input and attempts to typecast it into a floating point representation. [Round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) just rounds up to `n` significant digits.

```
float(3) #works on numbers 
float("5.2") #and strings too!

x = 9.09128239
#x = float("{0:.2f}".format(x)) #there are two steps here.

result = "{0:.2f}".format(x)

#result is a string "9.09" The rounding happened because of the precision listed during string formatting.

x = float(result) #just takes the string and converts to float

y = 9.09128239
y = round(y, 2) #directly works on the float and rounds it off.
```

Tl;Dr Just use round.

Answer (score 1):

This formats and parses a string, which is a lot of unnecessary work:

```
x = float("{0:.2f}".format(x))
```

This simple rounds the float, and will be much faster:

```
y = round(y, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**float()** is used for type conversion of data to the float-type, if applicable.

On the other hand, **round()** is used for rounding of the given value to the specified number of decimal places.

Just as a quick note, what you are doing above in the example for float() is taking a number, rounding it off to the specified number of digits (in your example, two), converting it into string, and then type casting it into float data type.

For more information on float(), you may visit this page:
[[Built in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main differences is that **`float` is a class and `round` is a function**. Using `float` does not round a number:

```
float('0.12345') #0.12345
```

but `round` does:

```
round(0.12345, 2) #0.12
```

Use `float` to convert something to a float, and use `round` to round off a float.